# Randomizing output of JavaScript Array

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a New Tab extension for Google Chrome that randomly displays a message but I can't seem to be able to get JavaScript to randomly output the phrase into HTML

```
var myArray = [
  "Test 1",
  "Test 2",
  "Test 3"
];

var randomItem = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];

document.phrase.body.innerHTML = randomItem;
```

Comment: What is `document.phrase`?

Comment: I don't understand your problem.  The random operation it's ok, but I don't understand this `document.phrase.body`.

Comment: try just `document.body.innerHTML = randomItem;`

Comment: Welcome to S.O., Josh. S.O. is a very active community... so, when asking a question, you should stick around for at least a couple of minutes, to see the questions/suggestions people do in the comments (and replying them, of course).

Comment: Sorry, thank you for the tip

Answer (score 0):

```
var myArray = [
  "Test 1",
  "Test 2",
  "Test 3"
];

var randomItem = myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];

document.body.innerHTML = randomItem;
```

Not sure what document.phase is but I think this is what you meant.

Comment: I messed up the the document.phrase part but after I fix that it still won't go through into the HTML